# Descriptor 'split' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'NoneType' object

Tags: python

Erm, I have ready-to-use code, and I'm sure it really works, but I get the following error:

```
descriptor 'split' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'NoneType' object
```

That's the whole def:

```
# Some utilities:
def get_name_and_link(link):
    # Get username from mutual friends link
    # Also returns mutual friends link as sometimes the link is weird
    global old_fb
    split = str.split (link, "/")
    if split[-2] == "www.facebook.com":
        # Corresponding to when user doesn't have a fb username.
        # We get their user ID instead, which is a number.
        name = str.split(split[-1], sep="=")[-2][:-3]
    elif split[-2] == "mutual_friends":
        # This means the link leads to a differently formatted mutual friends list.
        # We need to regenerate the friends list link from the user ID.
        name = str.split(split[-1], sep="=")[-1]
        link = "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=" + name + "&sk=friends_mutual"
        return [name, link] # We return the link directly
        # because we manually generated it, we know it's ok, no more to do with it.
    else:
        # This means the username is fine.
        name = split[-2]
    
    if old_fb:
        # Old fb gives link to full friends list, not just mutuals
        return [name, link + "_mutual"]
    else:
        return [name, link]

load_dotenv("facebook.env")
```

And here is the problem:

```
split = str.split (link, "/")
```

I'm sure it's not because of the code, I've tried it before (the same script) and it worked. No idea why it doesn't now.And this "unicode" makes me think I have to change "str.split", but hmmm. Waiting for opinions :)

Comment: Basically, the value that your variable `link` hols is `None`. It needs to be a defined string

Comment: Sounds like you did `get_name_and_link(None)`.  Don't do that.

Comment: Doesn't the split method take arguments?

Comment: @YondaimeHokage str.split takes optional arguments

Comment: @AlbertWinestein then what is the right solution? if at this time I want to do web scraping on facebook friends